# Error: The requested Style can not be used with this layer

Tags: geoserver, sld, gml, ogc

I'm trying to calculate the area of a polygon using the code from [this page](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/filters.html) and I'm getting the following error

> The requested Style can not be used with this layer.  The style specifies an attribute of `geometry` and the layer is `workspace:layer`

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
    xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <sld:NamedLayer>
        <sld:Name>style_osm_polygon</sld:Name>
        <sld:UserStyle>
            <sld:Title>'Polygon'</sld:Title>

            <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:And>
                            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                                <ogc:PropertyName>natural</ogc:PropertyName>
                                <ogc:Literal>water</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                                <ogc:Function name="area">
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>geometry</ogc:PropertyName>
                                </ogc:Function>
                                <ogc:Literal>1000000</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                        </ogc:And>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>7500000</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Fill>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#777777</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Fill>
                    </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
            </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>

        </sld:UserStyle>
    </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

I've tried capital `GEOMETRY`. Still get the same error.

Comment: what is your geometry column called then?

Comment: I'm not sure. How do I find out?

Comment: go to the layers menu and select workspace:layer and look at the bottom of the page